# how checking if a card has been clicked?

Tags: reactjs

I have a div(card) as below. When I click on this card, a detail page opens and when I come back to this page, I want the jackson text to be grayed out. Makes handleClick detail page open.

[image]
like this

[image]

```
export default function ListComponent({ handleClick }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    getMailbox()
      .then((response) => {
        if (response?.success) {
          setData(response?.data?.mails);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("err", err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    
      <div className={styles.messageBoxContainer}>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
            <div
              key={`item-container-${index}`}
              className={styles.mailItemContainer}
              onClick={() => {
                handleClick(item);
              }}>
                <div className={styles.mailOwner}>
                  <p className={isSelected ? styles.userEmailTextSelected : styles.userEmailText}>{item?.senderName}</p>
                </div>
             </div>
           ))}
        </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand question correctly but on click of card, you are navigating to another page, and when you come back on same page, previously clicked card should be grayed out, right ? 
If thats the case then if app is cra then use react router to send data while navigating back and forth and use that data lets say card id to gray out the card
Or if you are using browser navigation then you can sent card if as query from url.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `return` field to your `useEffect` hook so that when the element is unmounted its color change.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getMailbox()
    //...

    return () => {
        document.querySelector('#yourElementID').style.color = 'gray'
    }
 }, []);
```